# Applying input limits inside a for loop defining a char array (Tic Tac Toe)

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Here's my initial code - using which a user can play Tic Tac Toe by specifying what location in the char array they want to add zero or cross -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char a[3][3] = {{'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};
   cout << (char)a[0][0] << "    " << (char)a[0][1] << "    " << (char)a[0][2] << endl << endl << endl;
   cout << (char)a[1][0] << "    " << (char)a[1][1] << "    " << (char)a[1][2] << endl << endl << endl;
   cout << (char)a[2][0] << "    " << (char)a[2][1] << "    " << (char)a[2][2] << endl << endl << endl;

   int x, y;

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
   {
       cout << "Input x: ";
       cin >> x;
       cout << "Input y: ";
       cin >> y;

       system("clear");

       a[x-1][y-1] =  'X';

       cout << (char)a[0][0] << "    " << (char)a[0][1] << "    " << (char)a[0][2] << endl << endl << endl;
       cout << (char)a[1][0] << "    " << (char)a[1][1] << "    " << (char)a[1][2] << endl << endl << endl;
       cout << (char)a[2][0] << "    " << (char)a[2][1] << "    " << (char)a[2][2] << endl << endl << endl;

       cout << "Input x: ";
       cin >> x;
       cout << "Input y: ";
       cin >> y;

       system("clear");

       a[x-1][y-1] =  'O';

       cout << (char)a[0][0] << "    " << (char)a[0][1] << "    " << (char)a[0][2] << endl << endl << endl;
       cout << (char)a[1][0] << "    " << (char)a[1][1] << "    " << (char)a[1][2] << endl << endl << endl;
       cout << (char)a[2][0] << "    " << (char)a[2][1] << "    " << (char)a[2][2] << endl << endl << endl;
   }
}
```

In order to avoid the user's entry of the array index which is outside [1,3], I am trying to implement a an if condition

```
if(x <= 0 && x > 3)
{
    cout << "Wrong! Enter again. Input x: ";
    cin >> x;
}
```

It's not working. Since the for loop iterates 5 times each for X and O, either the output gets stuck at the 'Input X' stage or simply exits after 5 'Input X's.

Here's what I tried - which ended up taking 5 X inputs and then just exits -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char a[3][3] = {{'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};
   cout << (char)a[0][0] << "    " << (char)a[0][1] << "    " << (char)a[0][2] << endl << endl << endl;
   cout << (char)a[1][0] << "    " << (char)a[1][1] << "    " << (char)a[1][2] << endl << endl << endl;
   cout << (char)a[2][0] << "    " << (char)a[2][1] << "    " << (char)a[2][2] << endl << endl << endl;

   int x, y;

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
   {
       cout << "Input x: ";
       cin >> x;
       if(x <= 0 && x > 3)
       {
           cout << "Wrong! Enter again. Input x: ";
           cin >> x;
           continue;
       }
       else
       {
           continue;
       }

       cout << "Input y: ";
       cin >> y;
       if(y <= 0 && y > 3)
       {
           cout << "Wrong! Enter again. Input y: ";
           cin >> y;
           continue;
       }
       else
       {
           continue;
       }


       /*
       if(x <= 0 && x > 3)
       {
           cout << "Wrong! Enter again. Input x: ";
           cin >> x;
       }

       if(y <= 0 && y > 3)
       {
           cout << "Wrong! Enter again. Input y: ";
           cin >> y;
       }
       */

       system("clear");

       a[x-1][y-1] =  'X';

       cout << (char)a[0][0] << "    " << (char)a[0][1] << "    " << (char)a[0][2] << endl << endl << endl;
       cout << (char)a[1][0] << "    " << (char)a[1][1] << "    " << (char)a[1][2] << endl << endl << endl;
       cout << (char)a[2][0] << "    " << (char)a[2][1] << "    " << (char)a[2][2] << endl << endl << endl;

       cout << "Input x: ";
       cin >> x;
       if(x <= 0 && x > 3)
       {
           cout << "Wrong! Enter again. Input x: ";
           cin >> x;
           continue;
       }
       else
       {
           continue;
       }


       cout << "Input y: ";
       cin >> y;
       if(y <= 0 && y > 3)
       {
           cout << "Wrong! Enter again. Input y: ";
           cin >> y;
           continue;
       }
       else
       {
           continue;
       }


       /*
       if(x <= 0 && x > 3)
       {
           cout << "Wrong! Enter again. Input x: ";
           cin >> x;
       }

       if(y <= 0 && y > 3)
       {
           cout << "Wrong! Enter again. Input y: ";
           cin >> y;
       }
       */
       system("clear");

       a[x-1][y-1] =  'O';

       cout << (char)a[0][0] << "    " << (char)a[0][1] << "    " << (char)a[0][2] << endl << endl << endl;
       cout << (char)a[1][0] << "    " << (char)a[1][1] << "    " << (char)a[1][2] << endl << endl << endl;
       cout << (char)a[2][0] << "    " << (char)a[2][1] << "    " << (char)a[2][2] << endl << endl << endl;
   }
}
```

Why can I not just have an if statement after input, wherein it checks whether it is out of bounds, and if it is, it can ask the user again, and then proceed? - Which is what I am trying to implement.

Comment: Hint: `for loop` is iterating for 5 times irrespective of wrong user input. what you need is to continue the game until one user `success` or all the tiles are filled. Even you can add loop a loop for input until it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct operator would be || instead of &&.

By using &&, you are suggesting that BOTH x<=0 AND x>3 MUST concurrently happen for the IF statement to be taken!

It helps to try and read your statement aloud in English, would help you to make better sense of it :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why can I not just have an if statement after input, wherein it checks whether it is out of bounds, and if it is, it can ask the user again, and then proceed?

`if` statement checks for validity of the user input but it won't iterate  until the input is valid. You need to have a `loop` which runs until valid user input.

Something like below,

```
#include <iostream>

bool isGameCompleat(char a[3][3])
{
   /*check for all combination for the board for game complete*/
    if ((a[0][0] == a[0][1] && a[0][0] == a[0][2]) ||
        (a[1][0] == a[1][1] && a[1][0] == a[1][2]) ||
        (a[2][0] == a[2][1] && a[2][0] == a[2][2]) ||
        (a[0][0] == a[1][0] && a[0][0] == a[2][0]) ||
        (a[0][1] == a[1][1] && a[0][1] == a[2][1]) ||
        (a[0][3] == a[1][3] && a[0][3] == a[2][3]) ||
        (a[0][0] == a[1][1] && a[0][0] == a[2][2]) ||
        (a[0][3] == a[1][1] && a[0][3] == a[2][0]))
        return true;
    return false;
}

void printBoard(char a[3][3])
{
    std::cout << (char)a[0][0] << "    " << (char)a[0][1] << "    " << (char)a[0][2] << "\n\n\n";
    std::cout << (char)a[1][0] << "    " << (char)a[1][1] << "    " << (char)a[1][2] << "\n\n\n";
    std::cout << (char)a[2][0] << "    " << (char)a[2][1] << "    " << (char)a[2][2] << "\n\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    char a[3][3] = { {'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'} };

    int x, y;

    printBoard(a);

    for (int i = 0; (i < 9); i++)
    {
        int p;
        if ((i & 1) == 0) {
            std::cout << "X Turn ";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "O Turn ";
        }

        std::cout << "Enter the position ";
        std::cin >> p;  

        /*derived  row and column from 0 to 9 position*/
        x = (p / 3);
        y = (p%3) -1;

        /*Validity check for input if wrong request for new input
         * out of range check and non-repeated tile is selected
         */
        while (p < 0 || p > 9 || (a[x][y] =='X') || (a[x][y]=='O'))
        {   
            std::cout << "Wrong! Enter again: ";
            std::cin >> p;
            x = (p / 3);
            y = (p%3) -1;
        }

        if ((i & 1) == 0) {
            a[x][y] = 'X';
        }
        else {
            a[x][y] = 'O';
        }

        system("clear");
        printBoard(a);

        if (isGameCompleat(a))
        {
            std::cout <<(  (i & 1) ? "O" : "X") << " wins";
            break;
        }
        else if (i == 8)
        {
            std::cout << "Game is draw";
        }           
    }
}
```